# Is it possible to get the zipcode from a Stripe payment/card element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe react library's `CardElement` ([source](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#element-components)) and was wondering if there's any way to fetch the zip code a user enters from the Stripe flow after submission, possibly off the [PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) or elsewhere? After reading the docs (and considering the whole point of Stripe is to insulate the payment data) I'm assuming not but wanted to be sure.

I did see you can provide a default value for your payment element. So is the only/best solution to request a zip code separately before the Stripe flow, store it off, and then use it as the default value when then loading the Stripe element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe does not expose the customer's ZIP code through its payment or card element. This is due to security and privacy reasons. Stripe follows strict **PCI-DSS** compliance guidelines, which prioritize the protection of sensitive payment information.

If you require the customer's ZIP code for your business purposes, you can include a separate **input field** in your checkout flow to collect the ZIP code from the customer.

Comment: The zip code isn't covered by PCI-DSS compliance. Otherwise Stripe wouldn't expose that information in the dashboards and APIs.